# CSS and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I struggle with working with Internet Explorer.

Issue one:

I have used `min-height:100%` and I no that this does not work in IE.  How could I set the "min-height" in my css?

Issue two:

I have used

```
position: relative;
    z-index:50000;`
```

for my header and now its not aligned where it is required.

I have shiv installed

The link to the site is http://buddywalknz.org

**HTML (With CMS Tags)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {pyro:theme:partial name="metadata"}
<body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </header>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    {pyro:navigation:links group="header" indent="tab"} 
                </ul>   
            </nav>

<div id="mainContent">
    {if ('{pyro:page:is_home}' == TRUE)}
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    {else}
    <h1>{pyro:page:title}</h1>
    {/if}
    <p>
    {pyro:page:body}    
    </p>
        <div id="gallery">
                <div id="galleryMain"><img src="http://buddywalknz.org/uploads/default/files/accouncil_s.jpg" width="375" height="149" title="Proudly Supported by Auckland Council" alt="Auckland Council"></div>
            {pyro:streams:cycle stream="sponsors"}
            {entries}
                <div class="galleryLogo"><a href="{company_website}"><img src="{company_logo.thumb}" title="Proudly Supported by {company_name}" alt="{company_name}"></a></div>
            {/entries}
            {/pyro:streams:cycle}   
        </div>
</div><!-- Main Content Close -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html{
    background: url('../img/Body_BG.png') repeat-x 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body{
    width:960px;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;  
}
h1{
    margin:25px 0 0 25px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
}
header{
    height: 219px;
    width: 551px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header #logo{
    background:url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width:551px;
    height:219px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:50000;
}
nav{
    background:url('../img/navBG.png') no-repeat;
    float:right;
    width:135px;
    height:100%;
    padding:30px 0 0 0;
}
nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
}
nav li{
    margin:10px 0 0 -30px;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:5px;
}
nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ff9f30;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
#mainContent{
    float:right;
    background:url('../img/mainBG.png') no-repeat;
    width:707px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:-35px auto;
}
#mainContent h1{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
#mainContent a{
    color:#ff9f30;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#bottomBanner{
    background: url('../img/bottomBanner.png') no-repeat;
    width:478px;
    height: 47px;
    margin: -47px 0 0 300px;
}
#mainContent p{
    margin:0 30px 0 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align:justify;
}

#Video{

    margin: 30px 0 0 150px;

}

#Video #Vid{

    border: 5px solid #4e2b97;
}

.img{

    border: 5px solid #ff9f30;
}


a {
    outline: none;
}

a img {
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

a img.last {
    margin-right: 0;    
}

ul {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}


#img{

    margin-left: 25px;
}

#map{
    margin:0 0 0 115px;
}

/* Sponsor Gallery CSS  */
#gallery{
    width:707px;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    margin:0 0 0 30px;
}
#galleryMain{
    margin:0 0 0 150px;
}
.galleryLogo{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 8px 5px 0;
}
#galleryLogo img{
    border:none;
}
#galleryLogo a{
    border:none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* End Sponsor Gallery CSS  */

#contact-form{
    width:350px;
    margin:10px auto;
}

#contact-form label{
    float:left;
    width:175px;
}
#contact-form input{
    width:175px;
}
```

Comment: You know you're missing a closing `</head>` tag?

Comment: What version(s) of IE are we talking about here? Min-height tricks for IE: http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/ As for your header setting the z-index shouldn't change its position. Was it not position: relative prior to you changing it?

Comment: @DA I have IE8 but I also need to code for IE9 I guess.  The header loads fine in real browses just not IE

Comment: If you could create a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem, or show screenshots of what it does and what it should actually look like, that would help.

Comment: @MystereMan http://buddywalknz.org

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is.  In IE7, IE8, and IE9 the white area drops down below the purple.  I don't see what you're talking about.

Comment: A few more comments.  You're including the html5shiv twice.  That could mess some things up.  You still have not fixed your lack of a closing </head> tag (invalid markup can cause weird behavior).  It looks like the header problem may be related to when the html5shiv code gets called.  So fix the double include.

Comment: I think something is interfering with the html5shiv, try removing all your other scripts like the google analytics and take out the backup jquery script (just for testing).  I've also seen base tags mess things up as well.

Comment: One final suggestion, try moving your css file to AFTER the html5shiv script.  It could be that older versions of IE are applying styles before the shiv runs, and thus not really understanding what the html5 markup is.

Comment: @MystereMan I have tried the above and still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min-height does work in IE7 and later, but does not work in IE6.  Since IE6's usage is minimal, you should consider just ignoring it.

You have this code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Get rid if the first block, you only need the second.  This is what includes two copies of html5shim in IE7.

Comment: Still does not solve my issue http://cl.ly/3s3t3p391x1h2S2j2a1I  The white should be down at the end of the nav (purple)

Comment: @JessMcKenzie - It's really very difficult to know what's what going only by a screenshot.  The HTML you give doesn't help because we don't have the images.

Answer (score 0):

It's a barbaric -- and probably outdated -- solution, but IE does respect image bounds. Create a 1x1-px transparent GIF or PNG, stick it in your space with a height.

This will give you one pixel of shim too (call it leading if you want to be fancy) so make sure you adjust your CSS around that.